# Create hyperlink to jump to first cell whose value matches TODAY() in specified column

Tags: date, google-sheets, hyperlink

I have a column with an ordered list of dates in Google Sheets. I want to create a "Jump to today" cell at the top of the sheet that when clicked jumps to highlight the cells that match `TODAY()`, as well as the ones in the same row in the two adjacent columns to the left. For example:

G1034:G1037 = `TODAY()`

Click "Jump to today"

Want it to highlight E1034:G1037

Already tried these functions:

```
HYPERLINK()

VLOOKUP()

MATCH()
```

The issue is that I keep finding ways to return the values of the specified cells rather than the addresses. I can use `MATCH()` to return the row number and then `CONCAT()` to append that to the desired columns to get a cell address. However, my issue is with using that address inside a hyperlink.

Answer (score 1):

this is how you do it... it will jump on the cell with today's date:

```
="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16nnuzNRx_kGGJm1EBVX7kBT2bfW1-2TYwSiuaLF-QIA/edit#gid=1426770815&range="&ADDRESS(MATCH(TODAY(), A:A), 1, 4)
```

[image: 0]

for **G** column it would be: `&ADDRESS(MATCH(TODAY(), A:A), 7, 4)`